# KeyError when parsing JSON from API

Tags: python, json, api, python-requests

I need to parse data from a JSON file I've requested from an API. The API documentation provides an example code on how to implement it, however their method leads to the following KeyError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testing2.py", line 11, in <module>
    for flight in api_response['results']:
KeyError: 'results'
```

I've spent a lot of time looking for possible reasons but I can't find a solution that works for me. The Python file looks like this:

```
import requests

params = {
  'access_key': my_access_key'
}

results = requests.get('http://api.aviationstack.com/v1/flights?access_key=my_access_key&airline_name=Air%20India&flight_number=560')

api_response = results.json()

for flight in api_response['results']:
    if (flight['live']['is_ground'] is False):
        print(u'%s flight %s from %s (%s) to %s (%s) is in the air.' % (
            flight['airline']['name'],
            flight['flight']['iata'],
            flight['departure']['airport'],
            flight['departure']['iata'],
            flight['arrival']['airport'],
            flight['arrival']['iata']))
```

I've been able to read through the data with `print(api_response)`, however I can't parse through any of it since the key "results" simply doesn't seem to exist.

Edit:

This is the result of simply going to the URL or of `print(api_response)`, a large chunk of text:

{"pagination":{"limit":100,"offset":0,"count":4,"total":4},"data":[{"flight_date":"2020-09-02","flight_status":"landed","departure":{"airport":"Indira Gandhi International","timezone":"Asia/Kolkata","iata":"DEL","icao":"VIDP","terminal":"3","gate":"33","delay":4,"scheduled":"2020-09-02T07:15:00+00:00","estimated":"2020-09-02T07:15:00+00:00","actual":"2020-09-02T07:18:00+00:00","estimated_runway":"2020-09-02T07:18:00+00:00","actual_runway":"2020-09-02T07:18:00+00:00"},"arrival":{"airport":"Hyderabad Airport","timezone":"Asia/Kolkata","iata":"HYD","icao":"VOHS","terminal":"1","gate":null,"baggage":null,"delay":2,"scheduled":"2020-09-02T09:10:00+00:00","estimated":"2020-09-02T09:10:00+00:00","actual":"2020-09-02T09:09:00+00:00","estimated_runway":"2020-09-02T09:09:00+00:00","actual_runway":"2020-09-02T09:09:00+00:00"},"airline":{"name":"Air India","iata":"AI","icao":"AIC"},"flight":{"number":"560","iata":"AI560","icao":"AIC560","codeshared":null},"aircraft":{"registration":"VT-EXM","iata":"A20N","icao":"A20N","icao24":"800C4B"},"live":null},{"flight_date":"2020-09-01","flight_status":"landed","departure":{"airport":"Tirupati","timezone":"Asia/Kolkata","iata":"TIR","icao":"VOTP","terminal":null,"gate":null,"delay":null,"scheduled":"2020-09-01T10:20:00+00:00","estimated":"2020-09-01T10:20:00+00:00","actual":"2020-09-01T10:06:00+00:00","estimated_runway":"2020-09-01T10:06:00+00:00","actual_runway":"2020-09-01T10:06:00+00:00"},"arrival":{"airport":"Hyderabad Airport","timezone":"Asia/Kolkata","iata":"HYD","icao":"VOHS","terminal":"3","gate":null,"baggage":null,"delay":null,"scheduled":"2020-09-01T11:40:00+00:00","estimated":"2020-09-01T11:40:00+00:00","actual":"2020-09-01T10:51:00+00:00","estimated_runway":"2020-09-01T10:51:00+00:00","actual_runway":"2020-09-01T10:51:00+00:00"},"airline":{"name":"Air India","iata":"AI","icao":"AIC"},"flight":{"number":"560","iata":"AI560","icao":"AIC560","codeshared":null},"aircraft":null,"live":null},{"flight_date":"2020-09-01","flight_status":"landed","departure":{"airport":"Indira Gandhi International","timezone":"Asia/Kolkata","iata":"DEL","icao":"VIDP","terminal":"3","gate":"29B","delay":6,"scheduled":"2020-09-01T06:50:00+00:00","estimated":"2020-09-01T06:50:00+00:00","actual":"2020-09-01T06:56:00+00:00","estimated_runway":"2020-09-01T06:56:00+00:00","actual_runway":"2020-09-01T06:56:00+00:00"},"arrival":{"airport":"Hyderabad Airport","timezone":"Asia/Kolkata","iata":"HYD","icao":"VOHS","terminal":"2","gate":null,"baggage":null,"delay":null,"scheduled":"2020-09-01T09:20:00+00:00","estimated":"2020-09-01T09:20:00+00:00","actual":null,"estimated_runway":null,"actual_runway":null},"airline":{"name":"Air India","iata":"AI","icao":"AIC"},"flight":{"number":"560","iata":"AI560","icao":"AIC560","codeshared":null},"aircraft":{"registration":"VT-EXM","iata":"A20N","icao":"A20N","icao24":"800C4B"},"live":null},{"flight_date":"2020-09-01","flight_status":"landed","departure":{"airport":"Hyderabad Airport","timezone":"Asia/Kolkata","iata":"HYD","icao":"VOHS","terminal":null,"gate":null,"delay":null,"scheduled":"2020-09-01T12:45:00+00:00","estimated":"2020-09-01T12:45:00+00:00","actual":"2020-09-01T12:41:00+00:00","estimated_runway":"2020-09-01T12:41:00+00:00","actual_runway":"2020-09-01T12:41:00+00:00"},"arrival":{"airport":"Indira Gandhi International","timezone":"Asia/Kolkata","iata":"DEL","icao":"VIDP","terminal":"3","gate":null,"baggage":null,"delay":null,"scheduled":"2020-09-01T14:55:00+00:00","estimated":"2020-09-01T14:55:00+00:00","actual":"2020-09-01T14:42:00+00:00","estimated_runway":"2020-09-01T14:42:00+00:00","actual_runway":"2020-09-01T14:42:00+00:00"},"airline":{"name":"Air India","iata":"AI","icao":"AIC"},"flight":{"number":"560","iata":"AI560","icao":"AIC560","codeshared":null},"aircraft":null,"live":null}]}

Comment: Well, there is no such key as 'results' in the `api_response`
You could try accessing your [url](http://api.aviationstack.com/v1/flights?access_key=97e40ff9c669b83b8cd111aa181ba9a5&airline_name=Air%20India&flight_number=560) with your browser to see what is returned from the API

Comment: 1. You need to revoke the private key you just publicly shared. 2. And when you print the response, what do you see? Do you think there *is* a results key?

Comment: Can you please show the result of the code line " print(api_response) " ?

Comment: The result is too big for the comment, how can I share the result over here? I'm sorry I'm still very new to stackoverflow.

Comment: try `for flight in api_response['data']:`

Comment: @dh762 I did, and it gives me a `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable` error, which leads me to believe that it doesn't exist either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It accesses the key `data` instead of the key `results` (which probably does not exist in the response), and it does not raise a `TypeError` when accessing the `live` key within a flight object, which might be null (when it is on the ground).

```
import requests

params = {
  'access_key': access_key,
  'airline_name': 'Air India',
  'flight_number': 560
}


results = requests.get('http://api.aviationstack.com/v1/flights', params=params)

api_response = results.json()

for flight in api_response['data']:
    if flight.get('live') and not flight['live']['is_ground']:
        print('{} flight {} from {} ({}) to {} ({}) is in the air.'.format(
            flight['airline']['name'],
            flight['flight']['iata'],
            flight['departure']['airport'],
            flight['departure']['iata'],
            flight['arrival']['airport'],
            flight['arrival']['iata']))
    else:
        print("All flights landed.")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This gives me `format function is not called on str`.

Comment: fixed a small printing bug @YajasMalhotra

Comment: Thank you so much. This works. Just to be clear, the issue was that if a flight has landed it would give a nonetype for 'live'?

Comment: Yes, you accessed `flight['live']` but this is null, so it says _I cannot read null_